# Best practices for request parameters in GET/POST methods in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

What is the best practices for request a number of parameters in API URL and request a specific type for that.

For example I have the url: http://host/my_api/?param_1=p1&param_2=p2

Now I have in parameters.yml a parameter that say how many parameters I need to have in URL and in method I check if the parameters have a specific type that I need.

But I'm not sure if that is the best practice for request parameters. Is useful for me to know if a parameter is missing what is that for a specific error message.

Any advice or opinion?
Thanks!

*I use FOSRestBundle for create an API URL.

Comment: Hello, have a glance to http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Comment: I want to have the route under form: http://host/my_api/?param_1=p1&param_2=p2.

In link is described just routes under form: http://host/my_api/param_1/param_2

How I can change that?

Comment: What is the specific reason you want to have this kind of URL?

Comment: Technical specifications.

Comment: Sure?? Humpff, welcome to 2K17... Anyway, what API would you like to create with this routing?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to stick to query-parameters you could add a simple "checkFunction", for example if you want your two parameters to be required you could do sth as simple like this in your controller

```
/**
*@View
*/
public function apiAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->checkRequiredParams($request);
    ...
}


private function checkRequiredParams($request){
    $required = ["param_1","param_2"];

     foreach ($required as $r) {
        if(!$request->get($r)){
            throw new AccessDeniedException("ACCESS DENIED - missing parameter $r ");
        }
     }
     return true;
}
```

so it throws an exception if a parameter is missing, 
in this function you could also test for pattern or typecheck the value
dont forget to

```
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
```

if you want to make use of it